# How to initialize X509_STORE object in OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, cryptography, openssl, x509, ocsp

I'm trying to implement OCSP functions of OpenSSL as described [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+10.+Public+Key+Infrastructure/10.12+Checking+Revocation+Status+via+OCSP+with+OpenSSL/) and it requires X509_STORE object as a parameter. I have x.509 certificate that I want to check revocation status for, it's issuer certificate and the URL of the OCSP host.
How to properly initialize X509_STORE object having this information available? (I'm using C/C++ in XCode and OpenSSL v.1.0.0g)

Comment: Have you seen the example at http://mspmsp.brinkster.net/SPC/0596003943_secureprgckbk-chp-10-sect-5.html?

Comment: There are no doubt many examples in the openssl source code, especially the programs in the apps/ directory.